# Is there an interface to get node ip address from current worker using Dask?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, ray

I would like to know is there an interface to get node ip address from current worker (like using `ray.services.get_node_ip_address()`)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have already found the API.

```py
from distributed.utils import get_ip
```